# How to create a new custom carousel component from a PrimeNG carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, primeng

I am trying to create a generic component in my project which uses the [NgPrime Carousel](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v13/carousel) bases (such as indicators, navigators, etc) and only has to modify the HTML content of the items from my parent component.

[Stackblitz Demo Code From PrimeNG](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-carousel-demo)

I don't know if what I'm trying to do is possible but I'm looking to try to do it since the generic component I'm creating has several common methods and css styles that will be repeated every time a carousel must be created

**Code example of what I'm trying to do**

```js
// CustomCarouselComponent.ts
@Input() products
@Input() responsiveOptions
```

```html
<!-- CustomCarouselComponent.html -->
<p-carousel [value]="products" [numVisible]="3" [numScroll]="3" [responsiveOptions]="responsiveOptions">
                <ng-content ></ng-content>
</p-carousel>
```

```js
//ParentComponent.ts
products = [
        {
            "id": "1000",
            "code": "f230fh0g3",
            "name": "Bamboo Watch",
            "description": "Product Description",
            "image": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/09/03/46/alberta-2297204__340.jpg",
            "price": 65,
            "category": "Accessories",
            "quantity": 24,
            "inventoryStatus": "INSTOCK",
            "rating": 5
        },
        {
            "id": "1001",
            "code": "nvklal433",
            "name": "Black Watch",
            "description": "Product Description",
            "image": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/09/03/46/alberta-2297204__340.jpg",
            "price": 72,
            "category": "Accessories",
            "quantity": 61,
            "inventoryStatus": "INSTOCK",
            "rating": 4
        }
    ]
  responsiveOptions = [
    {
      breakpoint: '1024px',
      numVisible: 3,
      numScroll: 3
    },
    {
      breakpoint: '768px',
      numVisible: 2,
      numScroll: 2
    },
    {
      breakpoint: '560px',
      numVisible: 1,
      numScroll: 1
    }
  ];
```

```html
<!-- ParentComponent.html -->
<custom-carousel [products]="products" [responsiveOptions]="responsiveOptions">
    <ng-template let-product pTemplate="item">
        <div class="product-item">
            <div class="product-item-content">
                <div class="p-mb-3">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4 class="p-mb-1">{{product.name}}</h4>
                    <h6 class="p-mt-0 p-mb-3">${{product.price}}</h6>
                    <span [class]="'product-badge status-'+product.inventoryStatus.toLowerCase()">{{product.inventoryStatus}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</custom-carousel>
```